# SingleConnectionDataSource connection closed after about 40 minutes inactivity

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring, database-connection

We have a problem with `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource`?

We expect that the connection is never closed while the application is running, even if there is no traffic between application and db.

We configured datasource with
        `<property name="suppressClose" value="true"/>` what should solve the problem.

And the problem is that the connection is closed after about 30-40 minutes of inactivity (when there is no traffic between db and application).

Maybe someone with experience with SingleConnectionDataSource can help how to solve this bug or feature.

Comment: Could the connection be closed from the db side? Have you set any timeout value in your code?

Comment: which database are you using, mysql for eg has a wait_timeout property after completion of which the connection drops.

Comment: finally seems to be not java a problem. but anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: And what the problem was? I have that same. I added setSuppressClose(true); but problably does not help. How did you do?Oh.... 6 years :D

Answer (score 1):

If underneath SimpleConnectionDataSource, a MySql connection is used, then it will usually be dropped after 30-40 minutes of inactivity. Even if you use straight JDBC and create connection via:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager
                 .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?user=username&password=pass");
```

It will also be dropped after 30-40 mins.